# ffmpeg concatenate dynamic chunks (on-the fly)

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, streaming

The ffmpeg docs for concat lists the following way
`ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output`

The mylist.txt file contains file like
    file '/path/to/file1'
    file '/path/to/file2'
    file '/path/to/file3'

What I am looking is for a way to do this concat in a persistent way where the number of files can keep increasing, for example in livestreaming
I will be sending chunks of video (mp4 files) of 10 seconds each to my server and want to concat/stitch them together to output to a **RTMP** stream (for livestreaming)

If concat is not the proper way to do this, please suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same need. The problem with the playlist is that ffmpeg needs to read it read it entirely before the decoding starts, so you cannot create the videos on the fly. But refering to ffmpeg wiki : "it is possible to refer another list at the end of the current list"

They provide a batch script here

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Maybe you could use the second playlist for the videos not yet created, and then loop back to the first list...

Hope it helps. I'm not very good at shell scripts so please yell me if you managed to make it work.

Good luck !